# forceUpdate warning on Grid

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I am getting the warning below when I force update on a grid like this:

```
proxyConsole.js:56 Warning: forceUpdate(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

**Not sure how to amend where to put `forceUpdate()` so that it behaves correctly.**

```
const quoteList = [];

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      response: {},
      endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:4001"
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      const { endpoint } = this.state;
      const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
      this.theGrid.forceUpdate();

      socket.on("FromAPI", data =>  this.setState({ response: data }));
  }

  cellRenderer ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
      return (
        <div
          key={key}
          style={style} 
        >
          {quoteList[rowIndex][columnIndex]}
        </div>
      )  
  }

  render() {
      const { response } = this.state;


      if(Object.keys(response).length !== 0)
      {
        //console.log(response);

        const row = symbolRowDictionary[response.ticker];
        var column = 0;

        switch(response.type)
        {
          case 'bid':
            column = 1;
            break;
          case 'ask':
            column = 3;
            break;
          case 'last':
            column = 5;
            break;
          default:
            console.log('Unknown type');
        }

        quoteList[row][column] = response.size;
        quoteList[row][column + 1] = response.price;
        this.theGrid.forceUpdate();
      }

      return (
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        {
          <ul><li>Quote: {response.ticker} {response.type} {response.price} {response.size}</li></ul>           
        }

        <div>
          &nbsp;
        </div>

        <Grid
            ref={(ref) => this.theGrid = ref}
            cellRenderer={this.cellRenderer}
            columnCount={7}
            columnWidth={75}
            height={quoteList.length * 20}
            rowCount={quoteList.length}
            rowHeight={20}
            width={800}
        /> 

        </div>
      );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you add the definition related to `quoteList` ?

Comment: Amended. See post. It doesn't matter. The problem is in the forceUpdate.

Comment: Why are you calling `forceUpdate` in `componentDidMount` or `render`? I wouldn't expect to see either of those calls.

Comment: Where/How would you suggest I resolve the problem?

Comment: The only place I seem to be able to call forceUpdate on the Grid is precisely from the place I am not supposed to call it from. Anywhere else complains that this.theGrid is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I would move `quoteList` to component `state` as following:

```html
const endpoint: "http://127.0.0.1:4001";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      response: {},
      quoteList = [];
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);
    let _this = this;
    let {quoteList} = this.state;
    socket.on("FromAPI", data =>  { 
      if(Object.keys(response).length !== 0) {
        const row = symbolRowDictionary[response.ticker];
        var column = 0;
        switch(response.type)
        {
          case 'bid':
            column = 1;
            break;
          case 'ask':
            column = 3;
            break;
          case 'last':
            column = 5;
            break;
          default:
            console.log('Unknown type');
        }

        quoteList[row][column] = response.size;
        quoteList[row][column + 1] = response.price;
        _this.setState({ response: data, quoteList: quoteList })
      }    
    }));
  }

  cellRenderer ({ columnIndex, key, rowIndex, style }) {
    let {quoteList} = this.state;
    return (
      <div
        key={key}
        style={style} 
      >
        {quoteList[rowIndex][columnIndex]}
      </div>
    )  
  }

  render() {
    const { response, quoteList } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
        {
          <ul><li>Quote: {response.ticker} {response.type} {response.price} {response.size}</li></ul>           
        }
        <div>
          &nbsp;
        </div>
        <Grid
            ref={(ref) => this.theGrid = ref}
            cellRenderer={this.cellRenderer}
            columnCount={7}
            columnWidth={75}
            height={quoteList.length * 20}
            rowCount={quoteList.length}
            rowHeight={20}
            width={800}
        /> 

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

When `quoteList` is updated, its `length` will be updated accordingly and these changes will be passed to the child component `Grid`

---

**EDIT**

As you do not understand why does this code run, I will explan a little bit. If you don't know about React lifecycle, please take a look at this [illustration](https://res.cloudinary.com/hashnode/image/upload/v1458845434/necdybhogap8hp8fln1p.png)

1. `quoteList` is initialized as an empty array in `constructor`
2. `render` is called the first time. `cellRenderer` will be bound to this component, or `this` point to `App` component.
3. After component is mounted, `componentDidMount` will be triggered. Here is when we should fetch data from API. Within the function block (`data => {...}`) , `this` is pointing to the function itself. So before fetching the API, I have to assign `_this = this` to be able to call `setState`.
4. `setState` is executed, `render` will be triggered again and since `quoteList` is changed. Your `App` will be rendered differently according to new `quoteList`. Means the new `quoteList` now is passed to your `Grid`. `Grid` also re-render.

With this flow, you don't need to `forceUpdate`.

Comment: Inside cellRenderer: TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Comment: I think the problem is that it is not so simple to access 'this' inside a callback.

Comment: You have to bind `cellRenderer` in `constructor`: `this.cellRenderer = this.cellRenderer.bind(this)`

Comment: I realized after I posted that problem above. Now I got that working. I see no quotes coming from the other in the browser, even though I can console.log them. Also, I don't see the Grid.

Comment: My application works. Problem is forceUpdate is either in the wrong place, or my design is flawed in respect with React/react-virtualized Grid. I don't understand how your code resolves this underlying issue.

Comment: @Ivan: Add explanation

Answer (score 0):

After much experimentation and some online docs, I was able to solve it by putting `this.theGrid.forceUpdate` like this. There are no warnings, and `render` and `rendercell` are kept "pure"

```
componentDidMount() {
      const socket = socketIOClient(endpoint);

      socket.on("FromAPI", data => 
        {
          this.setState({ response: data });
          this.theGrid.forceUpdate();
        }
      );
  }
```